# How often do the news broadcasts occur?

Tags: splatoon

Every so often, a news broadcast occurs in Splatoon, heralding a change in the available Turf War stages. How often do these news broadcasts occur? Are they scheduled or random?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maps change [every 4 hours](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805617-splatoon/71777004?page=1).